# Gmail SMTPAuthenticationError when I attempt to send email via django

Tags: python, django, email, smtp, gmail

I'm using django-registration-redux and the forget password reset dialogue is working on my machine but it fails on the server. I get an SMTPAuthenticationError even though the local server is sending mails just fine. What could I be doing wrong?

This is the error I get:

```
(534, '5.7.14 
<https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignInsarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtwe\n5.7.14 Dz3CKtLMnsuR5AJAalqHTpUCJLECZAJKqbimLhjZ3dzjnEOfMck4BnpTZdlLbVRnkocGVe\n5.7.14 ghl_iEoinCscpmC_RWk8CxJ8MP61MyYKtKljt8gnet-NUj53mRP5ohGJsok8V1z1SWXzGa\n5.7.14 MrBjYMYDHU9MbPFopv5jWzFDQS_4Jop03AACxQAcSD1jGG1uQqFXjULQ2RE-wMPrCcyDKW\n5.7.14 Vq08guBEY2LqcSBp9L3jauD-a9i4> 
Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ra1sm18942520pab.24 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: Do you have two-factor auth enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have activated two-step verification, you need to turn that off. Also ,you can try another thing. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps,  allow access for the less secure app. Google might consider your server's sign-in process as less secure sign-in technology, which makes your account more vulnerable. So allowing access might help you.

Answer (score 5):

It is because Google blocks sign-in attempts from apps that do not use modern security standards (mentioned on their support page). You can, however, turn on/off this safety feature by going to the link below:

Go to this link and select Turn On

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Moreover, google blocks your IP when you try to send an email since its an unusual location, so, you can unblock in the next link

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563

and clicked in

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

More info…smtp mail